# Bytearray tamanho em disco

Tags: python, python-3.x

Vamos supor que eu converta uma imagem qualquer para `bytearray`.

```
with open("img.png", "rb") as imageFile:
  f = imageFile.read()
  b = bytearray(f)

print b[0]
```

Como faço para saber quanto de espaço em disco esse `bytearray` ocupará caso eu decida salvá-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função nativa [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) para se calcular o tamanho em bytes de um [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray), veja só:

```
with open("img.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    f = imageFile.read()
    b = bytearray(f)

print(len(b))
```

Saída:

```
384373
```

Comparando:

```
$ ls -al img.png 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lacobus lacobus 384373 Jul  3 17:24 img.png
```

Comment: Achei que `len()` devolveria a quantidade de elementos.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Exato, mas se é um *array de bytes*, o número de elementos será o número de bytes, concorda?

Comment: Verdade, porém achei que o `bytearray` nesse caso teria mais de um byte por posição.